# Diferenças entre formas de setar o charset no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Qual a diferença entre essas 2 formas de setar o charset na comunicação com o banco?

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=qualuqer_db;host=localhost;charset=utf8", "root", "");
```

e

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=qualuqer_db;host=localhost", "root", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET names utf8"));
```

Comment: Não há diferenças. A constante `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND ` serve apenas para informar ao PDO, que você deseja rodar aquele comando. Poderia ser, por exemplo, `[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET sql_mode=''"]`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr ahh sim, obrigado!

Comment: Uma vc usará o charset padrão que está definido no banco o outro você escolhe a formatação que deseja e como  o @ValdeirPsr disse você pode definir outros valores, isso somente "sobrescreve" o padrão do banco